# Restore read-only status when switching branches in msysgit

Tags: git, branch, perforce, msysgit

I'd like to use git branches to separate my local changes from the team's head code, which is stored in a Perforce repository.

Perforce uses the read-only flag on unchanged files, and won't update modified files if the read-only flag is not set, thinking that I might have changed them without putting them into a changelist.

I'd like to keep everything read-only on the master branch and modify files on other branches. Is it possible to make msysgit restore the read-only flag on the reverted files when checking out the master branch, so that p4 can sync everything?

Comment: It would also help to know what platform you're using - Windows with msysgit? *nix? Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a [git post-checkout hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout) with a bash script that sets the read-only flag...

Something along the lines of:

```
# (flag==1?) && (HEAD == master) ?
if [ $3 == 1 ] && [ `git symbolic-ref -q HEAD` == "refs/heads/master" ]
then
    # make everything in the given directory (recursively) read-only:
    chmod -w [ path_to_repo | . ]/* -R
fi
```

It looks like `./*` skips the `.git` folder (*hidden* files/folders in general?), but you should check that out to be sure. You probably also want to use the full path to your git repo instead of just `./*` so that it doesn't matter which dir/subdir you're in...

Comment: Can I have a list of files that were affected by the checkout? I'd like to avoid resetting the read-only flag of files excluded from version control.

Comment: updated the script for brute-force all-read-only; for just the files affected by the checkout, you might use something along the lines of `chmod -w \`git diff-index --cached --name-only $2\`` (since arg 2 is the OLD_HEAD) though I'm not if that does *exactly* what you want it to...

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answers. I will need to do the comparison of the old and new head and chmod only specific files. I'm not very familiar with bash scripting, though.

Comment: yeah, I was kinda hoping somebody else who uses P4 and is (intimately) comfortable with bash would chime in... anyways, you can execute `git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD@{1}` to see the difference between the current HEAD (HEAD@{0}) and the last place HEAD pointed... do that right after a branch back to `master` and you can see what files it would list...

Comment: and when you get a command that lists the files you want it to, just put it between the back-ticks in the chmod command like this: `chmod -w \`command_to_list_files here\`` - that'll execute that command and run `chmod` on the resulting filenames